# Show billing email from customer orders in WooCommerce My account Edit address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I Want to show meta "email" of a customers each order, but this is throwing an error.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_address_form', 'save_billing_email_to_user', 12, 1 );
function save_billing_email_to_user( $user_id ) {
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( 
        array( 
            'customer_id' => $user_id 
        )
    );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    foreach($orders as $ro => $inn){
             echo $ro['email'];
    }
}
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead the following revisited code that will query one order to get the billing email:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_address_form', 'save_billing_email_to_user', 12 );
function save_billing_email_to_user( $user_id ) {
    $orders = wc_get_orders(  array( 'customer_id' => $user_id , 'limit' => '1' ) );
    if ( ! empty( $orders ) ) {
        $order = reset( $orders );
        $order_id      = $order->get_id();
        $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
        echo $billing_email;
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Or you can show the billing email address from each order of a customer like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_address_form', 'save_billing_email_to_user', 12 );
function save_billing_email_to_user( $user_id ) {
    $orders = wc_get_orders(  array( 'customer_id' => $user_id ) );
    foreach( $orders as $order ){
        $order_id = $order->get_id();
        echo $order->get_billing_email() . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. First solution works. 2nd is throwing wordpress error. 2nd solution is better for further customization.

Comment: does this take the email from the last order or just one order at random?

Comment: accepted. One last question, how to get the order ID here? Want to use to update a meta feild using wc_update_order_item_meta( $order_id, 'calculated_field', $calculatedValue );

Comment: Have posted full code below can you please check. Cannot post new question due to limitation.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanBashir Sorry but the rule on StackOverFlow is one question at the time (by thread). So please Ask a **new question** clear and detailed, providing the code you tried. And please remove your code below as this is for answer, not for questions.